# nest ElasticClient client configuration with certificate and private RSA key

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest, client-certificates

So I have been building a backend job to collect information from a given ElasticSearch cluster, and now my problem is I am unsure how to initialize an ElasticClient such that I can access read-only methods such as "client.CatIndices()".

I have read through the Nest docs on this number times,
( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/working-with-certificates.html ) but quite honestly I am still unsure how to go about doing this in my specific case. I know that the Uri I am trying to access requires cert validation, and I have those keys and passwords in local files, but I am still unsure how to instantiate them within the ElasticClient object.

Basically my question is how do I go from :

```
var node = new Uri("(my uri)");

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);

//settings.ClientCertificate(new X509Certificate("filepath"); ???
var client = new ElasticClient((whatever args I need));
```

to being able to execute:

```
var result = client.CatIndices();
```

I am running on .net core 1.1. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit:

I have progressed a small amount on this issue by combining the client cert file and the corresponding client-key.pem into one pfx file through 
Openssl by running:

openssl pkcs12 -export -out merged-cert-and-key.pfx -in client.pem -inkey client-key.pem

Then I have created a new X509Certificate2 with this new output file. Next I added the certificate to the connection_settings.ClientCertificate property/method, which should authenticate all requests using this cert-key pair (which is what I want to happen)

I have also set the connection_settings.servercertificatevalidationcallback property to always return true (bypassing the CA cert validation requirements for now) by writing:
    settings.ServerCertificateValidationCallback((sender, cert, chain, errors) => true);

Now, by simply executing:
    var x = client.Ping();

Here is the response I get (x.debugInformation)...

Debug Information:
Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on HEAD: /

## Audit trail of this API call:

- [1] BadResponse: Node: "*My URI Node*" Exception: PipelineException Took: 00:00:00.5747770

  ## OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: One or more errors occurred. (Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration.) ---> System.AggregateException:One or more errors occurred. (Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration.) ---> Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration.

  at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.ThrowBadAuthPipelineExceptionWhenNeeded(IApiCallDetails response)
  at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TReturn](RequestData requestData)
  at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TReturn](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData`1 data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

  ## Audit exception in step 1 BadResponse:

Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration.
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.ThrowBadAuthPipelineExceptionWhenNeeded(IApiCallDetails response)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TReturn](RequestData requestData)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TReturn](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData`1 data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)

## Request:

## Response:

Edit 2:

Interestingly enough, the error message I have shown above from the response of client.Ping() is actually different from the error message I get from the response.debugInformation of client.CatIndices();

This error message for CatIndices reads:

Debug Information:  Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on GET: /_cat/indices

## Audit trail of this API call:

- [1] BadResponse: Node: *My URI (ommitted)* Exception: PipelineException Took: 00:00:00.7875970

  ## ServerError: ServerError: 401Type: security_exception Reason: "missing authentication token for REST request [/_cat/indices]"

## OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: One or more errors occurred. (Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration.) ---> System.AggregateException:One or more errors occurred. (Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration.) ---> Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration.

at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.ThrowBadAuthPipelineExceptionWhenNeeded(IApiCallDetails response)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TReturn](RequestData requestData)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TReturn](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData`1 data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

## Audit exception in step 1 BadResponse:

Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration.
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.ThrowBadAuthPipelineExceptionWhenNeeded(IApiCallDetails response)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TReturn](RequestData requestData)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TReturn](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData`1 data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)

## Request:

## Response:

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication token for REST request [/_cat/indices]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication token for REST request [/_cat/indices]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}},"status":401}

I am not sure if this additional information helps, but it is worth mentioning that the only response I really care about is client.CatIndices(), not client.Ping(). I merely assumed that Ping would require the same node authentication as CatIndices and thus were interchangeable for testing purposes.

Edit 3:

I backtracked and tried to establish a basic HttpConnection between my ElasticSearch uri and an HttpClient using my same pfx certificate. I was actually successful in making my Get request on _cat/indices, which tells me that the issue here is that the NEST ElasticClient is not actually verifying/authenticating the pfx certificate I added against my elastic search uri! This might suggest there are some bugs with the current NEST version when it comes to working with client certs.

It's a little disappointing, because I unfortunately already completed my assigned job assuming that I would have access to the client's CatIndices Response the NEST library offered me... Oh well!

Edit 4:
The way in which I got around this issue was by creating an instance of an HttpClient and HttpClientHandler and then manually passing the CAT query I originally intended to run  "/_cat/indices?format=json&pretty".

Step 1: I initialized the httpclienthandler and modified certain properties...

```
pfxCert = new X509Certificate2(_pfxCertFileName);//where the pfx file is the combined client cert and private rsa key from the openssl command I mentioned earlier


HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
clientHandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate {return true;};
clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(pfxCert);

client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
```

Step 2: Now the client has all it needs to make a request on elastic search so I created a new requestMessage and defined the necessary fields for my query...

```
var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
message.Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get;
message.RequestUri = new Uri(uri + CAT_QUERY); //where uri is obviously my elasticsearch cluster and the query is the /_cat/indices
```

Obtain the response by having the client send the message... this is what finally worked to satisfy the certificate crisis I had!!

```
var resp = client.SendAsync(message).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

string jsonIWanted = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Additional Information---
I attempted to use the NEST library on .net core version 1.1.0, running on Mac OS X El Capitan v 10.11.6 (this shouldn't matter too much since I was already building and running the program in docker), docker community edition v 17.03.1-ce-mac12, NEST and Elasticsearch.net versions 5.4.0

The way I tried to add the certs to the client in NEST were similar to the way I did it with the HttpClient...

```
X509Certificate2 pfxCert= new X509Certificate2(pfxFileName);//Same as loading pfx file before  

var node = new Uri(myURI); //same as before
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);

settings.ClientCertificate(pfxCert);//I tried loading this pfx in many other ways than just this, this just happens to be what remains in my sandbox code where I was troubleshooting this


settings.ServerCertificateValidationCallback( 
CertificateValidations.AllowAll);
ElasticClient  client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Then I tried to make the client calls as I mentioned before in previous edits which gave me those debug messages... Hope this helps whoever might want to investigate this use case any further!

Comment: What do you mean by "I know that the Uri I am trying to access requires cert validation"? Are you communicating with the cluster over HTTPS, or are you authenticating using Client Certificates? Or both?

Comment: I believe I am trying to do both. Also another problem I am having is apparently an error exclusive to Mac OSx .net projects: "Unhandled Exception: Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: The libcurl library in use (7.43.0) and its SSL backend ("SecureTransport") do not support custom handling of certificates. A libcurl built with OpenSSL is required. --"   I have researched this specific error but have not found an actual solution as many others seem to have had this issue as well.

Comment: Looks like it is possible to fix that issue by using a version of libcurl built against OpenSSL: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9728

Comment: yes, I have actually gone around that issue by running my program in a docker container which would not depend on the broken curl on OSx. Now my problem is I am incorrectly trying to authenticate against my ElasticSearch even though I have passed in a pfx containing the client cert and rsa key. The error I am getting when performing either "client.Authenticate()" or "client.Ping()" is "Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration."

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question and add this relevant detail? Could you also set `.EnableDebugMode()` on `ConnectionSettings` and show the output `result.DebugInformation`

Comment: Sure, I actually have printed the output for the response.DebugInformation from the client.Ping() call that I made; I will edit my question and add the error message it displays.

Comment: What version of NEST are you using, and what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: I am using NEST version "5.4.0" and I am targeting version "5.4.1", is that the problem right there? I didn't even realize they were different...

Comment: That's fine: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net#compatibility-matrix

Comment: Hmm.. any other thoughts? Is there more specific information I can present to you to better diagnose this issue? Appreciate it!

Comment: How did you establish a basic HttpConnection and use a HttpClient successfully? Can you add the code to your question? Can you also show how you are adding a client certificate to requests with NEST? The response in the audit trails of both API calls appears to indicate that no credentials were attached to the request. What OS platform are you running .NET Core on?

Comment: How did you establish a basic HttpConnection and use a HttpClient successfully? Can you add the code to your question? Can you also show how you are adding a client certificate to requests with NEST? The response in the audit trails of both API calls appears to indicate that no credentials were attached to the request. What OS platform are you running .NET Core on?

Comment: @krishnadg did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I was unable to resolve the issue within the NEST library, but I was able to authenticate with my elasticsearch cluster through a basic http connection using the "HttpClientHandler" and "HttpClient" objects. I will attach the code for how I did this in the post above.